# SSL certs errors with Gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I have setup a gem repo with https. We have internal singed certificates for which i have the singer/trust certificates.

But where to install those pem files i am not sure, hence getting the ssl error when trying to do a gem install

We are using CHEF, hence using the ruby installed as part of chef client install.

Have searched through the net the only aswer people have is a workaround, which is to change from https to http, but i want the gem repo to be setup with HTTPS (port 443)

Below is the error i get

```
[root@opslx0005 ~]# /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install lvm
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'lvm' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://myself.mydomain.com/artifactory/simple/infra-automation/gem-repo/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Tried with Ruby remote_fetcher to test

```
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -rrubygems/remote_fetcher -e 'p Gem::RemoteFetcher.new.fetch_http(URI.parse("https://myself.mydomain.com/artifactory/simple/infra-automation/gem-repo/latest_specs.4.8.gz")).bytesize'
```

UPDATE :

Found this online and this is my default pem file, updated the certs here but the error is still not going

```
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is probably to just set the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable to the CA certificate file. This should be picked up by Ruby's OpenSSL layer automatically.

Comment: Thanks tried, it, but not working. Still the same error

Answer (score 1):

From here: [SSL Error During Gem Installation (on MinGW64-MSys2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668472/ssl-error-during-gem-installation-on-mingw64-msys2/27668473#27668473)

Try downloading the http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem certificate. Then, point a special environment variable to it like that: `export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/cacert.pem` After that, issue an update command: `gem update --system` The problem should be solved after that. Relaunch the console and continue your work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, thought it was corporate proxy but I just need to update rubygems.
You might want to download the latest version from https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/

copy it to ruby gems folder
and then on cmd

```
C:\>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem
C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Hope that helps!