# SSL Error During Gem Installation (on MinGW64-MSys2)

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm using a MinGW64-MSys2 environment. When I try to install a package with `gem install <package name>` I get something like this `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)`

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what shell you use msys or mingw* and what ruby you use you need install ca-certificates package:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-ca-certificates
```

or

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates
```

or

```
pacman -S ca-certificates
```

Comment: wow, that's rather interesting! can be even better than my own solution... can't check it though right now, since I've already fixed the issue. maybe someone else can test and upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` certificate. Then, point a special environment variable to it like that: `export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/cacert.pem` After that, issue an update command: `gem update --system` The problem should be solved after that. Relaunch the console and continue your work.